# What is the proper regular expression for an unescaped backslash before a character?

Tags: regex

Let's say I want to represent `\q` (or any other particular "backslash-escaped character").  That is, I want to match `\q` but not `\\q`, since the latter is a backslash-escaped backslash followed by a `q`.  Yet `\\\q` would match, since it's a backslash-escaped backslash followed by a backslash-escaped `q`.  (Well, it would match the `\q` at the end, not the `\\` at the beginning.)

I know I need a negative lookbehind, but they always tie my head up in knots, especially since the backslashes themselves have to be escaped in the regexp.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to match. Given "\n" do you want to match: (1) the newline character, (2) the sequence "backslash, then n" , (3) the sequence "backslash, then a newline character"?

Comment: he's looking for a regex that will match a single character (non-space?) preceded by an ODD number of '\' characters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Updated:
My new and improved Perl regex, supporting more than 3 backslashes:

```
/(?<!\\)    # Not preceded by a single backslash
  (?>\\\\)* # an even number of backslashes
  \\q       # Followed by a \q
  /x;
```

or if your regex library doesn't support extended syntax.

```
/(?<!\\)(?>\\\\)*\\q/
```

Output of my test program:

```
q does not match
\q does match
\\q does not match
\\\q does match
\\\\q does not match
\\\\\q does match
```

Older version

```
/(?:(?<!\\)|(?<=\\\\))\\q/
```

Answer (score 3):

[Leon Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56671/6761181) got exactly what I was looking for.  I would add one small improvement for those who come here later:

```
/(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\q/
```

The additional `?:` at the beginning of the `(\\\\)` group makes it not saved into any match-data.  I can't imagine a scenario where I'd want the text of that saved.

Comment: True. If you want it even better, you could do
    /(?<!\\)(?>\\\\)*\\q/
It has a slightly better performance in case of a non-match.

Comment: Thanks James, works a charm. Example: To split a string at the first unescaped colon character in Python: `re.match(r'(.*?(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*):(.*)', text).groups()`. Works as expected with any number of backslashes.

Comment: @LeonTimmermans and James - hey - I've come up with an expression, that at least when I benchmark it on [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) seems to be ~35-40% faster in .Net, if you're interested: `(?<!(?<!\\)\\(\\\\)*)\\g` -- it also _only_ matches the character you want, rather than the entire expression (so, for `\\\\\g`, it will verify that `\\\\\ ` is even numbered, then match `\g` -- I believe yours matches `\\\\\g` - didn't seem like that was desired(?)

Answer (score 0):

[Now You Have Two Problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html).

Just write a simple parser. If the regex ties your head up in knots now, just wait a month.

Comment: Frank, the "now you have 2 problems" meme is just a (lame?) programmer's joke. RegExps have a bad press because of all the idiots out there who use it for HTML and XML. Otherwise, it is a legit tool if the content to be parsed is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language. Which "unescaped backslashes" happen to be...

Answer (score -1):

The best solution to this is to do your own string parsing as Regular Expressions don't really support what you are trying to do. (rep @Frank Krueger if you go this way, I'm just repeating his advice)

I did however take a shot at a exclusionary regex. This will match all strings that do not fit your criteria of a "\" followed by a character.

```
(?:[\\][\\])(?!(([\\](?![\\])[a-zA-Z])))
```