# Regex for matching quotes and single quotes

Tags: c#, regex, coldfusion

I'm currently writing a parser for ColdFusion code. I'm using a regex (in c#) to extract the name datasource attribute of the cfquery tag.

For the time being the regex is the following
    `<cfquery\s.*datasource\s*=\s*(?:'|")(.*)(?:'|")`

it works well for strings like
    `<cfquery datasource="myDS"`
or
    `<cfquery datasource='myDS'`

But it gets crazy when parsing strings like
    `<cfquery datasource="#GetSourceName('myDS')#"`

Obviously the part of the regex (?:'|") is the cause. Is there a way to only match single quote when the first match was a single quote? And only match the double quote when the first match was a double quote?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: I think this should work in C# you just need to do a back reference:

```
datasource\s*=\s*('|")(.*)(?:\1)
```

or perhaps

```
datasource\s*=\s*('|")(.*)(?:$1)
```

matches `datasource="#GetSourceName('myDS')#"` with a back reference to the first match with `\1`.

Of course, you cannot ignore the first capture group with `?:` and still have this work. Also, you may want to set the `lazy` flag so as not to match additional `"`'s

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using two different regexes if possible, or splitting the regex in a different way.

For a single regex, considering the question @Mike posted, 
`("[^"]*")|('[^']*')`
Then you can parse out the quotes.

The other potential way of doing this is by using lookahead/lookbehind, but that tends to get messy and isn't universally supported.

Comment: Looks to me like your expression has the second * in the wrong spot, should be ("[^"]*")|('[^']*')...unless your intention was to match many single-char constants like 'x''y''z'.

Comment: I think you're right. Fixed. This also doesn't handle escaped single or double quotes, but the question and answer are so old that I'll leave it incomplete (though now correct).

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this post:

> [How can I match a quote-delimited string with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375104/how-can-i-match-a-quote-delimited-string-with-a-regex)

They seem to be dealing with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It actually also gave a working answer to my issue.