# php - Replacing content inside double quotes, including double quotes

Tags: php, regex, replace

So I decided to have a stab at making a text highlighting system. At the moment, I'm just using `str_replace` to replace a word (e.g. `$rstr = str_replace("Console", "<c>Console</c>", $str` where `$str` is the input string. 
Something that stumped me was how to replace content inside of speech marks (") and quotes ('). For example, if the string "Console" turned into `Console.WriteLine("Words");`, how would I replace `"Words"` with `<sr>"Words"</sr>` (`<sr>` is defined in an external stylesheet)?

I had a though that I could use regex, but 1. I don't know how to write regex, and 2. I don't know how to use regex with `str_replace`.

---

My workaround solution:

```
function hlStr($original)
{
    $rstr = explode('"', $original);
    return $rstr[0].'<sr>"'.$rstr[1].'"</sr>'.$rstr[2];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In light of comments below, I think this will be a better resource for you: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

In order to find "anything can go here" you should use regular expressions. This is what they were made for. A regular expression for that might look something like the answers in this question:

[How can I match a quote-delimited string with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375104/how-can-i-match-a-quote-delimited-string-with-a-regex)

then you would use the function [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like this:

```
$return_value = preg_replace('/"[^"]+"/', 'replacement text', $str)
```

---

leaving this here anyway:

just escape the content with a backslash:

```
$rstr = str_replace("Console", "Console.WriteLine(\"$variable\");", $str)
```

this is mostly useful if you are using variables inside your strings. If it is just a straight text replacement, use single quotes:

```
$rstr = str_replace("Console", 'Console.WriteLine("Words");', $str)
```

the single quotes count everything but single quotes as just a character.

Comment: That isn't the problem. The problem is replacing the double quotes, and everything in-between (which is not pre-determined) with them, and contain them within `<sr>` tags. So `Console.WriteLine("RandomWords");` needs to turn into `Console.WriteLine(<sr>"RandomWords"</sr>);`. I am unsure of how to do this, because I cannot determine what "RandomWords" will be beforehand, and there could be multiple occurrences within the string that is having things replaced.

Comment: Yes, but I am unsure of how to implement this in `str_replace`, and I am unsure of how to write regex.

Comment: Plus, you have to capture the matched text to use it in the replacement.  Read about "capture groups" and "backreferences".

Comment: `$return_value = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', '<sr>"\1"</sr>', $str);` 
So `[^"]+` matches any string between double quotes.  The rounded brakets around them "capture" the match, so you can use it again in the replacement text with the backreference `\1`, wich means "use the first captured group.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think that regex are the best way to achieve this.  I would use a state machine.  This text would break the above example:

`Console.WriteLine("This string includes a double quote here \" and a single one here \' ");`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't go with your solution, but it helped me brainstorm a revised solution. Solution in main post.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution. Explode the whole string by ( " ) symbols, and then run a specific code to each second of them. This code does automatic do it to every second value after " item, which means, if you does : hej " lol ; it would change to : `hi <sr>" lol "</sr>` ; or if you do : hi " with " you ; it would change to : `hi <sr>" with "</sr> you` ; etc.

```
function wrapInside($text,$symbol)
    {
        $string = explode($symbol, $text);
        $i = 1;
        $QS = '';
        foreach( $queryString as $V )
        {
            ( $i == 1 ) ? ( $QS .= $V ) : ( $QS .= '<sr>"'.trim($V).'"</sr>' );
            ( $i == 1 ) ? ( $i = 0 ) : ( $i = 1 );
        }
        $queryString = trim($QS);
        return $queryString;
    }
```