# c# regex match var value

Tags: c#, regex, match

I want to match var value between quotes.
here's input:

```
bunch of other text, html tags, css 
var SECURITYTOKEN = "1354010802-f407561a1503fa33e8e316f058c0f0598ce5adad";
bunch of other text, html tags, css
```

result should be 1354010802-f407561a1503fa33e8e316f058c0f0598ce5adad

i was trying something like this:
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"var\sSECURITYTOKEN\s=");
but im totally confused.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375104/how-can-i-match-a-quote-delimited-string-with-a-regex

Comment: A good resource for testing .Net regex patterns online : http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variant finds only the part `var SECURITYTOKEN =`

use positive lookahead `(?=...)` and  positive lookbehind `(?<=...)`

```
String regexPattern = "(?<=var SECURITYTOKEN = \")(.*?)(?=\")";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, regexPattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex
`(?<=")(.*?)(?=")`

So it will be something like this

```
var regexPattern = "(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, regexPattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the same as og Grand answer but if your input looks like

```
var foo = "bar";
var SECURITYTOKEN = "1354010802-f407561a1503fa33e8e316f058c0f0598ce5adad";
var tata = "titi";
```

the following will be better :

```
var regexPattern = "(?<=var SECURITYTOKEN\s*=\s*\")(.*?)(?=\";)";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, regexPattern);
```