# Extracting phrases inside quotes that include a certain word

Tags: python, regex

I've been looking for a way to find the nearest encasing quotes or double quotes of a phrase in a paragraph.
For example, for the phrase -> AAAAA:

```
I am "looking for" a way that doesn't break: "Lorem
ipsum\" AAAAA" in this case. Or this AAAAA case. Or this 'AAAAA' case.
Isn't this annoying?
```

The output would be:

```
"Lorem ipsum \" AAAAA"  |  AAAAA  |  'AAAAA'
```

I'm really looking for any good way to do it (regex/parser or any valid method will be gladly accepted).

I tried to get some inspiration from [How can I match a quote-delimited string with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375104/how-can-i-match-a-quote-delimited-string-with-a-regex), but it wasn't really what I was looking for.

An example for something I tried was this (and then use code to filter out matches that include the "AAAAA" in them. This failed though when there was another ' in the end of the sentence.:

```
(["'])(?:\\\1|[\s\S])*?(AAAAA)?(?:\\\1|[\s\S])*?\1|AAAAA
```

If it's any help, I'm going to be using this solution in Python code.

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the code you came up with? Please show the code to see what issue you have got.

Comment: Just a hint: you will have to use regex with a bit of code, or a parser. Doing this with just regex is too much pain, and most probably won't work without certain assumptions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew added. If there is anything else let me know.

Comment: I thought you were looking for something like https://ideone.com/sBQzUc

Comment: That's almost it! Because I was trying to capture the surrounding quotes as well, I moved them inside the capturing group. 
One thing I noticed is the \b'\b part. Do you think there is any way to bypass it some other way? Imagine text with the phrase - """I used to love the song Space Truckin'. It is 'AAAAA'."""  -> Here the ' is at the end of a word and kinda messes up the solution. Again, thanks a ton!

Comment: See https://ideone.com/K5y4sf or https://ideone.com/GLgvi7

Comment: I actually can't thank you enough, and although I don't understand the regex completely (I guess I'm not proficient enough), this gives me the intended results. You can make this the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?xs)
(?<!')(?:'{2})*\B('\b[^'\\]*(?:(?:\\.|\b'\b)[^'\\]*)*') # Single quoted string literal
|                                                       # or
(?<!")(?:"{2})*\B("\b[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|\b"\b)[^"\\]*)*") # Double quoted string literal
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AlFzPT/2). *Details*:

- `(?xs)` - verbose and dotall modes on
- `(?<!')` - no `'` allowed immediately on the left
- `(?:'{2})*` - zero or more `''` substrings
- `\B` - there must be start of string or a non-word char immediately to the left
- `('\b[^'\\]*(?:(?:\\.|\b'\b)[^'\\]*)*')` - Group 1, a single quoted string literal pattern:

  - `'\b` -  a `'` that must be followed with a word char
  - `[^'\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
  - `(?:(?:\\.|\b'\b)[^'\\]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

    - `(?:\\.|\b'\b)` - a `\` followed with any one char or a `'` that is enclosed with word chars
    - `[^'\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
  - `'` - a `'` char.
- `|` - or
- `(?<!")(?:"{2})*\B("\b[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|\b"\b)[^"\\]*)*")` - Group 2: a double quoted string literal (analogous to the preceding single quoted string literal pattern).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GLgvi7):

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile( r'''(?xs)
(?<!')(?:'{2})*\B('\b[^'\\]*(?:(?:\\.|\b'\b)[^'\\]*)*') # Single quoted string literal
|                                                       # or
(?<!")(?:"{2})*\B("\b[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|\b"\b)[^"\\]*)*") # Double quoted string literal
''')
 
text = "I am \"looking for\" a way that doesn't break: \"Lorem\nipsum\\\" AAAAA\" in this case. Or this AAAAA case. Or this 'AAAAA' case.\nIsn't this annoying?"
print(f"This is the text: {text}")
matches = [f'{x}{y}' for x,y in pattern.findall(text) if 'AAAAA' in f'{x}{y}']
print(matches)
# => ['"Lorem\nipsum\\" AAAAA"', "'AAAAA'"]
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to make this work for quoted strings that start with a non-word char. e.g.:
What about this case "$ Lorem AAAAA Ipsum"
Any ideas?

Comment: @cakelover Please check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AlFzPT/3).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when the string is encased in a ().
For example, It is ('AAAAA')

Comment: @cakelover Try a non-word boundary, [as shown here](https://regex101.com/r/AlFzPT/4).

Comment: Last case - I've found this breaks in this situation https://regex101.com/r/EI3q9U/1

Comment: @cakelover Well, that is out of regex reach, you need a dedicated language parser in this case.